# Update records using map values

Tags: map, update, bulkification

Sorry for the beginner question -- I'm generating a `Map<ID,String>` where the ID is an OpportunityId and the String is the value of a custom field on the Opportunity that I want updated. How would I go about updating the records via the contents of the map?

Comment: Please update this question with your existing code so that we can quickly identify problem and propose better solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
// Your map
Map<Id, String> m = new Map<Id, String>();

// Update needs to know the type so create objects of the right type
Opportunity[] updates = new Opportunity[] {};
for (Id id : m.keySet()) {
    updates.add(new Opportunity(Id = id, FieldName__c = m.get(id)));
}
update updates;
```

Note that there is also a [put(String fieldName, Object value)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) method available so if you didn't want to hard code the field name you could use that to set the value by name.

Comment: what is this declaring: Opportunity[] updates = new Opportunity[] {};        ? thanks

Comment: @jaw999 That is exactly the same as `List<Opportunity> updates = new List<Opportunity>();` but using the more compact (and interchangeable) array syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The **put** method of maps update an item when it finds the item:
From the documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm

"**If the map previously contained a mapping for this key, the old value is returned by the method and then replaced.**"

Here you have an example:

Note: *myList is String and myMap is String, Integer*

```
List myList = new List();
myList.add('key1');
myList.add('key1');
myList.add('key2');

Map myMap = new Map();
for (String item : myList)
{
    if (myMap.containsKey(item))
    {
        Integer contador = myMap.get(item);
        myMap.put(item, contador + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        myMap.put(item, 1);
    }
}

System.debug('$$$$$$$$$ myMap: Size: ' + myMap.size() + ' ; ' + myMap);
}
```

It prints the following:

```
$$$$$$$$$ myMap: Size: 2 ; {key1=2, key2=1}
```